# Why can my js code set values to undefined array indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As I know **an `Array` element in JavaScript can itself be another `Array`,** hence creating layers of arrays within one another. I am tring to define an array like:

> [Array(821), Array(821), Array(821), Array(821)]

As You see, this is an array with 4 elements each of which will contain an array of 821 elements.

Now, I also know **Arrays can be dynamically resized** using `Array.push("new value")` method, otherwise an `undefined` error will be thrown. Therefore, I defined each and every one of the array elements as being an array itself:

```
var htmlOBJs = {};
    htmlOBJs.tabular = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    htmlOBJs.tabular.push([]);
}
```

Now, when I want to access an element inside the inner array `htmlOBJs.tabular[2][100]`, **surprisingly** no undefined error is thrown. Why? Am I not supposed to push indexes up the inner array *up to* 100?

Comment: an array is an object. accessing an array by index is no different than accessing an object using bracket notation. `tabular[2]` is an array, and `tabular[2][100]` is the property named `100` of that array. it will equal undefined, but accessing it is not itself an error.

Comment: I see. Thank you @DanO

Answer (score 0):

The reason the undefined error isnt thrown is as you `push` to the tubular array this causes a new entry created. This means now it is a multidimensional array. To cause the undefined error to throw you would have to go 3 levels deep.

There is an interesting reason for empty arrays which has been described way better but basically the first parameter for the Array constructor is a size and not actually filling this array: [image]

to do this you can use the fill method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill - you may need to map over this after to make sure these are unique values.